# cardinal number arithmetic regarding exponentiation

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I am reading a textbook and it is stated that

> we know that $\aleph_0\lt\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}=c$, but that $c^{\aleph_0}=c$. so we might be tempted to conjecture that if $m \gt \aleph_0$, then $m^{\aleph_0}=m$. But this is false. In fact, for every cardinal number $k$, it is possible to find an $m\gt k$ for which $m^{\aleph_0}\gt m$ and also to find a $p\gt k$ for which $p^{\aleph_0}=p$.

I think there is a typo in the book, does the author mean the following statement?

> But this is false. In fact, for every cardinal number $k$, it is possible to find an $m\gt k$ for which $m^k\gt m$ and also to find a $p\gt k$ for which $p^k=p$.

Also can you come up with an example where

> $m\gt k$ and $m^k>m$

I know the above statement is true if $k\lt m\lt \aleph_0$ for example $3^2\gt3$. Is there any example where $m\gt k\ge \aleph_0$ for the above statement to be true?

Thanks.

Comment: No, the author most likely meant their statement as written. What makes you think that it was printed incorrectly?

Comment: @MeesdeVries the fact that even though $m\gt k$ is mentioned, it does not appear in the inequality. Basically, I don't understand what does the statement mean.

Comment: It's saying that there are arbitrarily large cardinals $m$ with $m^{\aleph_0}>m$ and arbitrarily large cardinals $p$ with $p^{\aleph_0}=p$ if you want to phrase it without using $k$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the author likely meant the statement as written. It is true, and it makes sense in context.

Let me expand a bit on the author's statement. You have learned that $\aleph_0 < \aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$. That is: there are more sequences of natural numbers than natural numbers. You might find this surprising, or not, depending on your previous intuition about infinity. In a way it makes sense: *infinite sequences* of something have a lot more degrees of freedom than single elements of that same thing.

Then you learn that $\mathfrak c^{\aleph_0} = \mathfrak c$. So apparently for $\mathfrak c$, this much larger cardinal, it is no longer true that taking infinite sequences of elements of $\mathfrak c$ produces *more* sets. This might lead you to believe one of two things: (1), maybe $\mathfrak c$ is an unusual exception, and it's the only cardinal for which this is true, or there are only a couple more; or (2), maybe $\mathfrak c$ is just so *large* that taking infinite sequences doesn't "help" anymore. (For comparison, you might know that for any finite $n > 0$, and any infinite cardinal $\kappa$, it is true that $\kappa^n = \kappa$; maybe the same is true for $n = \aleph_0$ if you take $\kappa$ large enough.)

The author then dispels both these potential misconceptions: no matter how large a cardinal $\kappa$ you take, you can always find two cardinals $\mu, \nu > \kappa$ such that $\mu^{\aleph_0} = \mu$ and $\nu^{\aleph_0} > \nu$. That is, whether or not exponentiation by $\aleph_0$ adds new elements is not just determined by size: as cardinals get larger and larger, you will always find examples of both behaviors.

**Edit:** You mention in a comment that the author delays the proof. I think this is likely for good reason: the obvious way I would prove the above fact would be via [König's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_(set_theory)#K%C3%B6nig's_theorem_and_cofinality), but likely you have not even learned what cofinality is. However, one of the parts is pretty easy to prove: namely that you can find $\mu > \kappa$ with $\mu^{\aleph_0} = \mu$.

Proof: let $\lambda$ be any cardinal greater than $\kappa$, and define $\mu = \lambda^{\aleph_0}$. Then we have that
$$
\mu^{\aleph_0} = \left(\lambda^{\aleph_0}\right)^{\aleph_0} = \lambda^{\aleph_0 \times \aleph_0} = \lambda^{\aleph_0} = \mu.
$$
Here, we have only used the definition of $\mu$, the fact that $\left(\alpha^\beta\right)^\gamma = \alpha^{\beta \times \gamma}$, and that $\aleph_0 \times \aleph_0 = \aleph_0$, both of which are pretty easy to prove if you have not already done so.

Comment: The author states that "there is a proof for the statement but omitted since it is a bit too complicated to look at now." I wonder is there a simple proof or simple example to illustrate the above statement besides $c$.

Comment: @KennethNye, I've updated my answer with a proof of half the statement. I don't know of a truly elementary way to prove the other half.

Comment: @Kenneth Although the author meant what they wrote, the version you ask about is also true, and for the same reason (König's theorem): as long as $\kappa>1$ there is an $\frak m>\kappa$ with $\frak m^\kappa>\frak m$ and also a $\frak p>\kappa$ with $\frak p^\kappa=\frak p$. This is of course only interesting for $\kappa$ infinite.

Comment: @Kenneth You also ask for examples of $\frak m>\kappa$ with $\frak m^\kappa>\frak m$. For $\kappa$ infinite this is really what König's theorem gives you: You just need to pick $\frak m$ of *cofinality* at most $\kappa$. For example $\aleph_{\kappa^++\kappa}$ is both larger than $\kappa$ and of cofinality at most $\kappa$. The sum in the subindex here is in the sense of ordinals.